# Error 1045 while configuring mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-connection

I can install the mysql but while configuring it i am getting error like this:
** 1045 : access denied for user root@loaclhost.**
 i can install it i cant configure it. Please help...I am quite new to this.

Comment: Off-topic for SO: try [sf].

Comment: did you specify a pwd for the root user?  have you tried resetting the pwd, logging in as root and tried againn?

Answer (score 1):

did you specify a password for the root user - there is no pwd for the root user by default so if you have not specified a password for the root user, you can connect like this:

```
mysql -u root
```

if you specified a password, you can connect like this:

```
mysql -u root -p   (at which point you will get prompted for the password)
```

If you need to reset the password for root, you can try this:

1. Stop MySQL
2. Restart it manually with the skip-grant-tables option: mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
3. Run the MySQL client: mysql -u root
4. Reset the root password manually with this MySQL command: UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
5. Flush the privileges with this MySQL command: FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

It would be good if you create a separate user and not use root for your DB operations (where you don't need root).

Comment: was this helpful and were you able to resolve the issue?